# XElement return node value

Tags: xml, linq, xpath

I have an XElement that looks like this;

```
    <VideoFiles>
  <VideoFileInfo>
    <VideoType>1000</VideoType> 
    <FormatCode>1000</FormatCode> 
    <Url>http://www.idontwantthisvalue.com</Url> 
  </VideoFileInfo>
  <VideoFileInfo>
    <VideoType>WMVOriginal</VideoType> 
    <FormatCode>1004</FormatCode> 
    <Url>http://www.iwanthitsvalue.com</Url> 
  </VideoFile>
```

I need to grab the  value that has a sibling with a  value of 1004.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically:

```
/VideoFiles/VideoFileInfo[FormatCode='1004']/Url
```

Exactly

> I need to grab the value that has a
>   sibling with a value of 1004.

```
/VideoFiles/VideoFileInfo/*[.='1004']/following-sibling::*[1]
```

or

```
//*[.='1004']/following-sibling::*[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure LINQ to XML solution:

```
    XElement xdoc = XElement.Load("test.xml");
    var myUrl = xdoc.Descendants("VideoFileInfo")
                    .Where(x => x.Element("FormatCode").Value == "1004")
                    .Select(x => x.Element("Url").Value)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="VideoFiles/VideoFileInfo[FormatCode='1004']/Url"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs only your desired value:

```
http://www.iwanthitsvalue.com
```